# uwp - Write registry at installation time

Tags: windows, uwp, registry

I have one common installer that I have used with DesktopAppConverter to create my AppX (Universal windows platform). In installer, I write some Windows registry that at the moment I cannot write using MyAppX. This is the command that I have used to create package:

```
DesktopAppConverter.exe -Installer "C:\Users\jngd\Desktop\app-installer\setupapp.exe" -InstallerArguments "/SILENT" -Destination "C:\Users\jngd\Desktop\app" -PackageName "MyApp" -Publisher "CN=AppExample" -Version 0.0.0.1 -Verbose -MakeAppx -Sign
```

Any way to allow full functionality of common installer in AppX installation time?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add registry keys as part of installation with a converted Desktop app -- one of the main benefits of using a converted app is that there is a clean uninstall.

You can write to the registry at runtime, but typically it will be virtualized into your own private location.

If you provide more information on which key(s) you're writing, and why, there might be other solutions.